# Dealing with dropdown with Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, forms, selenium, dropdown

I want to automatize clicking on a random option in [a Google Form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdgHE-s1jVy9BaJIxfnUdWXZljtqF0Akfh6v_esss2yqkfLSA/formResponse) dropdown lists like the following one:

[image]

As the structure look like the following one:

```
<div jscontroller="liFoG" jsaction="rcuQ6b:vZc4S;O22p3e:zjh6rb;b2trFe:eVidQc;JIbuQc:d3sQLd;" class="freebirdFormviewerComponentsQuestionSelectRoot"><div role="listbox" aria-expanded="true" class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectEl appsMaterialWizMenuPaperselectSelect freebirdFormviewerComponentsQuestionSelectSelect freebirdThemedSelectDarkerDisabled noMaxWidth isOpen" jscontroller="YwHGTd" jsaction="click:cOuCgd(LgbsSe); keydown:I481le; keypress:Kr2w4b; mousedown:UX7yZ(LgbsSe),npT2md(preventDefault=true); mouseup:lbsD7e(LgbsSe); mouseleave:JywGue; touchstart:p6p2H(LgbsSe); touchmove:FwuNnf; touchend:yfqBxc(LgbsSe|preventMouseEvents=true|preventDefault=true); touchcancel:JMtRjd(LgbsSe); focus:AHmuwe; blur:O22p3e;b5SvAb:TvD9Pc;" jsshadow="" jsname="W85ice" aria-describedby="i2 i3" aria-labelledby="i1"><div jsname="LgbsSe" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true"><div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectOptionList" jsname="d9BH4c" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true"><div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectOption appsMaterialWizMenuPaperselectOption freebirdThemedSelectOptionDarkerDisabled exportOption isSelected isPlaceholder" jsname="wQNmvb" jsaction="" data-value="" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0"><div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectRipple exportInk quantumWizMenuPaperselectSelectedRipple" jsname="ksKsZd" style="top: 23.7px; left: 123px; width: 176px; height: 176px;"></div><span jsslot="" class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectContent exportContent">Sélectionner</span></div><div class="appsMaterialWizMenuPaperselectOptionSeparator" role="presentation"></div><div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectOption appsMaterialWizMenuPaperselectOption freebirdThemedSelectOptionDarkerDisabled exportOption" jsname="wQNmvb" jsaction="" data-value="Yes" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1"><div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectRipple exportInk" jsname="ksKsZd"></div><span jsslot="" class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectContent exportContent">Yes</span></div><div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectOption appsMaterialWizMenuPaperselectOption freebirdThemedSelectOptionDarkerDisabled exportOption" jsname="wQNmvb" jsaction="" data-value="No" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1"><div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectRipple exportInk" jsname="ksKsZd"></div><span jsslot="" class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectContent exportContent">No</span></div><div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectOption appsMaterialWizMenuPaperselectOption freebirdThemedSelectOptionDarkerDisabled exportOption" jsname="wQNmvb" jsaction="" data-value="I'm not sure" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1"><div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectRipple exportInk" jsname="ksKsZd"></div><span jsslot="" class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectContent exportContent">I'm not sure</span></div></div><div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectDropDown exportDropDown" role="presentation"></div></div><div class="exportSelectPopup quantumWizMenuPaperselectPopup appsMaterialWizMenuPaperselectPopup" soy-server-key="5:pZtlf" jsaction="click:dPTK6c(wQNmvb); mousedown:uYU8jb(wQNmvb); mouseup:LVEdXd(wQNmvb); mouseover:nfXz1e(wQNmvb); touchstart:Rh2fre(wQNmvb); touchmove:hvFWtf(wQNmvb); touchend:MkF9r(wQNmvb|preventMouseEvents=true)" role="presentation" jsname="V68bde" style="min-width: 178px; top: 281.5px;"><div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectOption appsMaterialWizMenuPaperselectOption freebirdThemedSelectOptionDarkerDisabled exportOption isSelected isPlaceholder" jsname="wQNmvb" jsaction="" data-value="" aria-selected="true" role="option" tabindex="0"><div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectRipple exportInk quantumWizMenuPaperselectSelectedRipple" jsname="ksKsZd" style="top: 23.7px; left: 123px; width: 176px; height: 176px;"></div><span jsslot="" class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectContent exportContent">Sélectionner</span></div><div class="appsMaterialWizMenuPaperselectOptionSeparator" role="presentation"></div><div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectOption appsMaterialWizMenuPaperselectOption freebirdThemedSelectOptionDarkerDisabled exportOption" jsname="wQNmvb" jsaction="" data-value="Yes" aria-selected="false" role="option" tabindex="-1"><div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectRipple exportInk" jsname="ksKsZd"></div><span jsslot="" class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectContent exportContent">Yes</span></div><div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectOption appsMaterialWizMenuPaperselectOption freebirdThemedSelectOptionDarkerDisabled exportOption" jsname="wQNmvb" jsaction="" data-value="No" aria-selected="false" role="option" tabindex="-1"><div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectRipple exportInk" jsname="ksKsZd"></div><span jsslot="" class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectContent exportContent">No</span></div><div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectOption appsMaterialWizMenuPaperselectOption freebirdThemedSelectOptionDarkerDisabled exportOption" jsname="wQNmvb" jsaction="" data-value="I'm not sure" aria-selected="false" role="option" tabindex="-1"><div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectRipple exportInk" jsname="ksKsZd"></div><span jsslot="" class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectContent exportContent">I'm not sure</span></div></div></div></div>
```

I need to click on the list first, and then on a given option.

I tried to deal with it with this bunch of code:

```
                 lists = container.find_element_by_class_name("quantumWizMenuPaperselectOption.appsMaterialWizMenuPaperselectOption.freebirdThemedSelectOptionDarkerDisabled.exportOption.isSelected.isPlaceholder")
                 if lists !=[]:
                     for list in lists:
                         option = container.find_element_by_class_name("quantumWizMenuPaperselectOption.appsMaterialWizMenuPaperselectOption.freebirdThemedSelectOptionDarkerDisabled.exportOption.isSelected")
                         if option:
                             option.click()
```

But I have an issue with it ...

Comment: _have an issue with it_, What is that issue?

Answer (score 1):

Use below code:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('quantumWizMenuPaperselectOptionList').click()
options = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.exportSelectPopup div.quantumWizMenuPaperselectOption')
random_index = randint(1, len(options))
options[random_index].click()
```

**Explanation:**

1. Locate the dropdown element and perform click
2. Identify all dropdown value element and store into a list
3. Generate a random number between starting index and max size of list (lets say list size is 4 and start index in 1 so it will generate a random number between 1 and 4)
4. Click on random number index of option list which will pick a dropdown value randomly